insert multiple values ​in hsqldb
when I try to enter multiple values ​​using insert into in the libreoffice tools:
INSERT INTO "SERVICES TABLE" ("NUMBER", "FAULT DESCRIPTION")
VALUES
(32323, 'ASDF'), (3234, 'DASFF');
I get the following error:
1: Unexpected token: , in statement [,]
Does anyone know the correct format for multiple values. I have tried all the formats and I can't get any valid ones
when I try to enter multiple values ​​using insert into in the libreoffice tools:
Does anyone know the correct format for multiple values. I have tried all the formats and I can't get any valid ones

This should work in HSQLDB 2.0 and higher:
INSERT INTO T (A,B) VALUES ((1,2),(3,NULL), (DEFAULT,6))

However, if you're using Base's built-in HSQLDB 1.8 embedded setup (not recommended except for development) then here is the relevant documentation. While it's not entirely clear to me, it doesn't look like multiple rows are possible unless using a SELECT statement, and testing seems to verify this.
So, either convert to a proper split database setup and install a modern version of HSQLDB or another engine such as PostgreSQL, or else use multiple INSERT statements.

Try using multiple statements:
INSERT INTO "SERVICES TABLE" (NUMBER, "FAULT DESCRIPTION") VALUES (32323, 'ASDF');
INSERT INTO "SERVICES TABLE" (NUMBER, "FAULT DESCRIPTION") VALUES (3234, 'DASFF');

